# Reducing PSD File size/selections

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In trying to reduce file size for PSD, does eliminating saved selections do anything? I've found lots of useful tips, but none relating to selections. Thanks.

Comment: Have you deleted them and looked?

Comment: Okay, so I finally had time to try it. Files are large illustrations.  Starting with 3 layers @ 129MB. Eliminate 36 selections brings it down to 114MB. Adding a white fill layer on top drops it to 70MB (presumably because it doesn't have to save a preview).  Now we all know.

Comment: In other words, less layers + layer masks = smaller file size yes.

Comment: May I ask why you need to reduce the PSD file size? Might be easier in the long run to invest in more memory.

Comment: Because I have to upload it and when the deadline's tight. I want to speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well, each type of layer *can each easily add an extra* 20mb+ to your unflatten .psd file *at high resolution.*

If you're using the same mask for many layers, you can group these layers in the same folder and use the mask on the folder instead.

But since you don't want to remove your selections or layers, there is something else you might want to try and that can help reduce the file size.

In Photoshop, all the layers that are not showing on your artboard are still "hidden" in the gray area around your design. If you imported big images that go off the working area, they are still calculated as pixels in your document and they add up to the weight of your file.

If you don't mind losing that kind of data, you can crop your psd file or erase these unused parts to get rid of that "dead weight". It's not always the ideal solution, but you can do some clean-up there on some layers.

[image: How to lower the file size of an unflatten .psd Adobe Photoshop file]

Comment: > "each type of layer adds a 20mb." I supose the layer size depends on the canvas size, the content of it, and the compression settings.

Comment: I added some conditional specifications that the image is probably high resolution and a simple psd. I assumed it was high resolution since low resolution are rarely so heavy they need to be optimized when the layers are not flattened!