# How to transfer large design files and images via internet

Tags: file-size, resource-recommendations

I need to transfer a .psd file that contains different layers online. It's too large for gmail and will take to long to send via physical mail.

What are some ways I can send these files?

Comment: Personally I use [dropbox](http://dropbox.com/), but I've seen bunch of people use [wetransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/), which has file size limit of 2gb, unless you want to pay for it. But if you are ok paying for a service... personally I'd rather pay for [dropbox](http://dropbox.com/) than [wetransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/), since it has way better features.

Comment: Ok.Thanks.This information also helpful for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no discernible relation to Graphic Design. It’s all the same for any large file.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "Any method to reduce the layer size without affecting the quality?" Well in fact it's also a duplicate then. The question was a bit incomplete.

Comment: What i meant that i am working as a designer.I need to transfer our photographs[ mainly wedding .psd ]files.It contains layers.Too big sizes.After completion of my work it will transfer to next section like printing.So the file upload via gmail taking long time.What i do for the time consuming.Some cases i have to work from home also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the following

- Wetransfer.com
- Google Drive
- Dropbox
- Finally if you have a personal website, you can upload directly to you FTP and send a link

Comment: Wetransfer.com is great because  you or the recipient are not required to have an account or to log in to retrieve the files. Very easy to use!

Comment: indeed i love it

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anyone mention this service so I present to you [Copy](http://www.copy.com).

It's more or less like Dropbox with a free plan:

- 15GB of cloud storage
- 1 user
- No maximum file size limit
- 30 day file revision history
- 30 day file recovery
- Sync desktop files
- Mobile app access

I was happy to see that you can sync a folder with another user and split the size on your account in half. I have a folder worth 7GB that I share with my gf and we both have only 3.5GB taken from our individual accounts.

**But what I think interests you the most is that you can share a folder with someone and password protect it ;). Take a look and good luck.**

Answer (score 0):

I've found that instead of trying to send the .psd itself, it'd be best to upload it to a cloud (Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive by Microsoft, etc - the three I use because they're simple and mostly free), and send a link to the file. Emailing .psd files can take a while, much like sending a large PDF. Only thing I haven't figured out is how to password protect files and folders. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To share files online you can try [hightail.com](https://www.hightail.com/compare-plans); the person receiving the file doesn't need an account, it's less annoying than dropbox and hasn't been hacked yet. There's a free plan too for smaller files up to 250mb.

Or upload your files by FTP in your hosting (if you have one) and share the url. Make sure to make that folder not accessible.

Comment: Any method to reduce the layer size without affecting the quality?

Comment: Delete useless layers and layer masks (or apply them if it's alright) remove "useless" parts that are not visible (see here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39331/reducing-psd-file-size-selections/54945#54945) and you can always compress the files by "zipping" it (.zip) or even using "rar" as compression (eg. WinRar) if the person you send it to can manage that.

Comment: For the purpose of wedding photography,all layers must be used.After it will be send to another person.That will be take more time.So before sending if any method is available please mention.

Comment: Compression might help then (.zip). You should have access to the compression tool this by right-clicking on the folder or file you need to send usually (eg."archive" or "compress") r go have a look in your application folder or "start menu" (I guess). ONE BIG SUGGESTION: It's better to not send your files all in one big .zip or email if you have many. Split your package in a few batches instead, make sure to identify everything properly. For example "files 1 of 4", "files 2 of 4", etc.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite way is thru MyAirBridge (www.myairbridge.com). It is great and simple to use service with which you can send up to 20 GB for free and even up to 100 GB with profile.

Answer (score -1):

You can pretty much up and download it everywhere you want.

Just google "file sharing" and you'll get thousands of websites you can choose from

I personally use wwe.mega.nz for big files because its one of the only file sharing websites that don't limit the speed

Comment: This is not very helpful

Comment: It answers the question